# Backup SQL Server database using c# and Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, smo

I'm working with C#, Visual Studio 2005, WinForms.

I'm writing an application that will backup all the DBs in all of our SQL Server instances
I'm refering

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
```

Actions:

1. Backup every db on every SQL Server instance.
2. copy the backup to a local machine(where the application is running)
3. deleting the backup file from the remote server - this actions fails regarding to permission issues

here is the code::

```
Backup bkpDatabase = new Backup();
// Set the backup type to a database backup
bkpDatabase.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
// Set the database that we want to perform a backup on
bkpDatabase.Database = DbName;// cmbDatabase.SelectedItem.ToString();

// Set the backup device to a file
//new BackupDeviceItem(saveBackupDialog.FileName, DeviceType.File);
BackupDeviceItem bkpDevice = new BackupDeviceItem(NewName, DeviceType.File);

// Add the backup device to the backup
bkpDatabase.Devices.Add(bkpDevice);
// Perform the backup
bkpDatabase.SqlBackup(SD.SrvSql);
File.Copy(Source, PathDestination + "\\" + fileName);

File.Delete(Source);
```

I'v tried to work with:

```
File.Move
File.Delete
```

They both don't work

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get an error? What does *They both don't work* mean?

Comment: Guess that he means copy then delete or move? Neither of the solutions work.

Comment: Did you try this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.backup.sqlbackup.aspx

Comment: May be you should sql server agent to take the back up periodically.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions (delete) on the source directories for the user executing the app?